# Modify locker location using Valence API

Tags: desire2learn

Our institution is looking at linking a cloud storage service with D2L and we were investigating the possibility of modifying the path of individual user's lockers to the cloud storage path using Valence.

The APIs appear to allow the creation/deletion/editing of files and folders within a users locker, however is there the ability to edit the location of the locker itself?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, the root location of a user's locker is not modifiable through the Valence Learning Framework APIs.